# Is covariance matrix required to compute SVD?

Tags: pca

In the PCA lecture of Andrew Ng's ML in Coursera, it is computing the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ from `X` and use it to compute SVD. Is covariance matrix of X required to compute SVD of X?

I think SVD can handle non-square matrix and no need to get a square matrix which is required in eigen vector decomposition, but not SVD.

[image]

Comment: I found this helpful when I was learning PCA http://mlsp.cs.cmu.edu/courses/fall2014/lectures/extra/pca.pdf  see the section "SVD and PCA" which addresses your question.  Short answer - yes SVD can get you the principal component vectors "directly" without having to form the covariance matrix.

Comment: Thanks @bogovicj for the answer and the good material.